# Why the x axis is not same as the bar plot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to plot the bar chart of top 5 country export based on different coffee products by using ggplot in R. The bar will represent the country, the x axis is based on the products, and the y axis is the currency. The problem is, my x-axis is not same as the bar plot.

The input:

```
structure(list(Product = c("Instant coffee", "Instant coffee", 
"Instant coffee", "Instant coffee", "Instant coffee", "Other than instant coffee", 
"Other than instant coffee", "Other than instant coffee", "Other than instant coffee", 
"Other than instant coffee", "Roasted coffee paste mixtures", 
"Roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Roasted coffee paste mixtures", 
"Roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Other than roasted coffee paste mixtures", 
"Other than roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Other than roasted coffee paste mixtures", 
"Other than roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Other than coffee extracts, essences, and concentrates", 
"Other than coffee extracts, essences, and concentrates", "Other than coffee extracts, essences, and concentrates", 
"Other than coffee extracts, essences, and concentrates", "Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", 
"Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", 
"Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", 
"Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", 
"Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", 
"Coffee husks and skin", "Coffee husks and skin", "Coffee substitutes containing coffee", 
"Coffee substitutes containing coffee", "Coffee substitutes containing coffee"
), Country = c("THAILAND", "JAPAN", "CHINA", "SINGAPORE", "HONG KONG", 
"SINGAPORE", "THAILAND", "CHINA", "JAPAN", "HONG KONG", "THAILAND", 
"SINGAPORE", "CHINA", "HONG KONG", "CHINA", "HONG KONG", "THAILAND", 
"SINGAPORE", "SINGAPORE", "THAILAND", "CHINA", "HONG KONG", "CHINA", 
"SINGAPORE", "HONG KONG", "THAILAND", "JAPAN", "THAILAND", "SINGAPORE", 
"HONG KONG", "THAILAND", "SINGAPORE"), Value = c(113811367, 54117310, 
22787412, 20630048, 3307630, 14428372, 12166136, 5313127, 3610526, 
1551410, 26151746, 14538914, 12248674, 8205716, 122342698, 59969399, 
41142402, 21618883, 8983854, 4444070, 2379029, 261907, 114333179, 
53470883, 36296114, 10421164, 28482, 3056256, 34373, 2219796, 
190127, 169475), Position = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

This is the code that I write:

```
 ggplot(export2022, aes(x = Product, y = Value, fill = Country, group = desc(Position))) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge2", width = 0.7) + 
   labs(
     title = "Different coffee products exported by Malaysia\nunder the category of coffee      extracts and substitutes for the\ntop five destination countries in 2022",
     x = "Products under category of coffee extracts and substitutes",
     y = "Millions RM"  # Update the y-axis label
   ) +
   scale_y_continuous(
     breaks = seq(0, max(export2022$Value), by = 2e7),  # Set breaks at every 10 million
     labels = function(x) scales::comma(x, scale = 1e-6)  # Format labels in millions
   ) +
   scale_fill_manual(
     values = c("THAILAND" = "#922B21", "SINGAPORE" = "#1F618D", "CHINA" = "#AF7AC5", 
               "HONG KONG" = "#76D7C4", "JAPAN" = "#FF7676"),
     name = "Country"
   ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Instant\ncoffee", 
                               "Other than\ninstant coffee", 
                               "Roasted coffee\npaste mixtures",
                               "Other than,\nroasted coffee\npaste mixtures",
                               "Other than,\ncoffee extracts,\nessences, and\nconcentrates",
                               "Other than\ncoffee mixture with\nvegetable fat,\nprepared from      extracts,\nessences, or\nconcentrates",
                               "Coffee husks\nand skin",
                               "Coffee\nsubstitutes\ncontaining\ncoffee")
   ) + 
   theme_bw() +
   theme(
     legend.position = "bottom",
     legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 8),
     legend.box = "vertical",
     legend.justification = "center",
     legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
     panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
     plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
     panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
     panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
```

[image: The chart that i got]

Comment: The main issue with your code is that you assign the wrong labels, i.e. your categories are ordered alphabetically whereas you are assuming they are ordered according to the order of the data. As a result you are assigning labels to the wrong categories. Drop `scale_x_discrete` and you will get the right labels. And if you want the same order  for the product categories as in your data then convert `Product` to a factor using e.g. `forcats::fct_inorder()` and to wrap your labels you could use `stringr::str_wrap` as in the answer by Jon.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to have R do the line wrapping for you:

```
  ggplot(export2022, aes(x = factor(stringr::str_wrap(Product, 20)) |> 
                           forcats::fct_reorder(Value, max) |> 
                           forcats::fct_rev(),
                         y = Value, fill = Country, group = desc(Position))) +
...
(and remove the `scale_x_discrete` section)
```

[image]

Comment: updated with sorting. in general, whenever you want a custom filtering of categories, you want your variables to be "factors". here, I use the `forcats` package to help with the arranging.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have this code:

```
 group = desc(Position)))
```

Try to remove that group. Here is the sample full code:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Your data
export2022 <- structure(list(Product = c("Instant coffee", "Instant coffee", "Instant coffee", "Instant coffee", "Instant coffee", "Other than instant coffee", "Other than instant coffee", "Other than instant coffee", "Other than instant coffee", "Other than instant coffee", "Roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Other than roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Other than roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Other than roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Other than roasted coffee paste mixtures", "Other than coffee extracts, essences, and concentrates", "Other than coffee extracts, essences, and concentrates", "Other than coffee extracts, essences, and concentrates", "Other than coffee extracts, essences, and concentrates", "Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", "Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", "Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", "Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", "Other than coffee mixture with vegetable fat, prepared from extracts, essences, or concentrates", "Coffee husks and skin", "Coffee husks and skin", "Coffee substitutes containing coffee", "Coffee substitutes containing coffee", "Coffee substitutes containing coffee" ), Country = c("THAILAND", "JAPAN", "CHINA", "SINGAPORE", "HONG KONG", "SINGAPORE", "THAILAND", "CHINA", "JAPAN", "HONG KONG", "THAILAND", "SINGAPORE", "CHINA", "HONG KONG", "CHINA", "HONG KONG", "THAILAND", "SINGAPORE", "SINGAPORE", "THAILAND", "CHINA", "HONG KONG", "CHINA", "SINGAPORE", "HONG KONG", "THAILAND", "JAPAN", "THAILAND", "SINGAPORE", "HONG KONG", "THAILAND", "SINGAPORE"), Value = c(113811367, 54117310, 22787412, 20630048, 3307630, 14428372, 12166136, 5313127, 3610526, 1551410, 26151746, 14538914, 12248674, 8205716, 122342698, 59969399, 41142402, 21618883, 8983854, 4444070, 2379029, 261907, 114333179, 53470883, 36296114, 10421164, 28482, 3056256, 34373, 2219796, 190127, 169475), Position = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 )),
                           class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -32L))


# Create a factor of Product with levels ordered by Position
export2022$Product <- factor(export2022$Product, levels = unique(export2022$Product[order(export2022$Position)]))

ggplot(export2022, aes(x = Product, y = Value, fill = Country)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7) + 
  labs(
    title = "Different coffee products exported by Malaysia\nunder the category of coffee extracts and substitutes for the\ntop five destination countries in 2022",
    x = "Products under category of coffee extracts and substitutes",
    y = "Millions RM"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, max(export2022$Value), by = 2e7),
    labels = function(x) scales::comma(x, scale = 1e-6)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("THAILAND" = "#922B21", "SINGAPORE" = "#1F618D", "CHINA" = "#AF7AC5", 
               "HONG KONG" = "#76D7C4", "JAPAN" = "#FF7676"),
    name = "Country"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 8),
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.justification = "center",
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), # Rotate x-axis labels
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
```

Here is the sample output:

[image]

Here is the [sample R fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/8tS8FaJx2Cd)

Comment: `group = desc(Position)` isn't the issue. Actually this is needed to get right grouping of the bars from smallest to highest for each x axis category. The issue is that the OP assigns the wrong labels via `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) but actually I want the bar to arrange in descending order for every products and I want the products name on x axis write in new line instead of long sentence. Anyways, thank you.